# List facebook likes underneath every url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I was trying to find the best way to count number of likes for a facebook page url and after googling a lot and playing with the code, i have a code like the one given below. It outputs the likes, name of the page and then the link. I wish to know:
1. How can i use the  html tag to convert the link into hyperlink so that I can have something like "Click here to visit"
2. How can monitor performance of 25+ fb_id on an hourly basis with a sorted order (descending) on likes

```
<?php
$fb_id = '36922302396';
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . urlencode($fb_id);
$result = json_decode( file_get_contents($url) );
printf("%s %s %s", $result->likes, $result->name, $result->link);
?>
```

Edited code as per solution provided

```
<?php
$fb_id = '36922302396';
$pic = 'https://www.facebook.com/' . urlencode($fb_id) . '/picture?type=square';
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . urlencode($fb_id);
$result = json_decode( file_get_contents($url) );
echo $result->likes , " " , $result->name , " " , "<a target='_blank' href=\"" . $result->link . "\" ><img src = $pic></a>";
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1)

How about

```
<?php
$fb_id = '36922302396';
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . urlencode($fb_id);
$result = json_decode( file_get_contents($url) );
//printf("%s %s %s", $result->likes, $result->name, $result->link);
echo "<a href=\"" . $result->link . "\">Link</a>";
?>
```

You can also use

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/<?php $fb_id ?>">Link</a>
```

For 2)

If you know the Page's IDs, then you can just concatenate them to the following :

```
GET /?ids=40796308305,339150749455906&fields=id,name,likes,talking_about_count
```

The result looks like the following

```
{
  "40796308305": {
    "id": "40796308305", 
    "name": "Coca-Cola", 
    "likes": 88365218, 
    "talking_about_count": 635936
  }, 
  "339150749455906": {
    "id": "339150749455906", 
    "name": "Pepsi", 
    "likes": 33321925, 
    "talking_about_count": 208761
  }
}
```

For hourly stats, you need to setup your script via `cron` etc. and write the results to a database.

Comment: Is there a limit to add multiple IDs? can I add 1000+ urls separated by comma?

Comment: I think Facebook allows a querystring up to 2000 characters.

Comment: oh! ok. thanks. I have edited my original question with your solution and added a _blank open in new window feature too. struggling to put an img src instead of "Click here to visit" confused on how to put the syntax properly src link is graph.facebook.com/36922302396/picture?type=square where 36922302396 is the same fb_id used. I tried something but it does not show because the url is redirecting to another url. Can you please check?